# Updating the UI from subclassed buttons in Kotlin

Tags: android, button, kotlin, subclass, android-button

I have subclassed a Button in Kotlin. There are about 10 buttons in the UI that will inherit this new button class, `CustomButton`.

For a very simple proof of concept, I am trying to set some of the buttons' `halfAlpha` property to true, to change the alpha to `0.5f`.

```
class CustomButton : Button {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs){
        if (halfAlpha){
            this.alpha = 0.5f
        }
    }
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs,
        defStyleAttr)

    var halfAlpha = false
}
```

Inside of my MainActivity class, I am calling this function in onCreate:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    lockButtons()
}

private fun lockButtons(){
    button1.halfAlpha = true
    button2.halfAlpha = false
    button3.halfAlpha = true
    button4.halfAlpha = false
    button5.halfAlpha = true
    // etc...
}
```

The problem is... button 1, button 3 & button 5's alpha never changes to 0.5.

If I set `var halfAlpha = true` in CustomButton, then all of the buttons alpha are 0.5.

**How can I change the alpha on button 1,3, 5 using this subclassed Button class?**

Comment: You're only setting the `Button`'s `alpha` in its constructor, and you're not setting those `halfAlpha` values until well after the `Button`s were constructed during the layout inflation in `setContentView()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this function in your CustomButton

```
fun setAlpha(isHalfAlpha: Boolean) {

    if (halfAlpha){
        this.alpha = 0.5f
    }
}
```

invoke it

```
button1.setAlpha(true)
button2.setAlpha(false)
button3.setAlpha(true)
button4.setAlpha(false)
button5.setAlpha(true)
```

Hope this helps.